# Flow mapping visualization using a road layer

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, visualisation, origin-destination, flow-map

I am trying to illustrate travel using a flow map on a road layer. My data is:

- city of origin
- destination
- number of travelers

How do I use a polygon city layer (or point) and a road layer, with line thickness representing volume of travelers?

I am using QGIS.

Comment: Do you have a layer that has the following fields: `From`, `To`, and `travellers`? If not, you might have to build a line layer from your point layer (City nodes) and your text data (Number of travellers). Please clarify!

Comment: i would have to build that layer, it is in my SQL database. I dont have it qgis yet. I am curious about the process of overlaying the travel on to the road network, what pluggin to use? thanks!

Comment: Do you also have to do the routing algorithm from city to city? or is it going to be a straight line? or do you know the roads that they will take? How many points do you have to do this for? I'm just curious if you can edit the question and be very detailed about the specifics and requirements, and based on that I can perhaps post an answer. As of yet, it seems some details are missing, and it'll be very crucial to understand what data you have, what you're trying to accomplish, so a detailed / direct answer could be provided

Comment: The data I have: city From, To, and Travellers. no actual data on their route, but it is safe to assume they take the shortest route. There are two main highways through the Canadian rockies and the map is hoping to show where snowmobilers come from and go to, to help the avalanche centre better focus their efforts on road side safety info. I would like the travel to follow major roadways, as it will look a lot nicer than a bunch of point to point lines.

Comment: Don't snow mobiles have their own trails but they can cross highways at certain locations? I'm just scared that this could be a problem a lot bigger than you anticipated initially. However, I'm not sure if you know this but you can edit your original question to reflect the additional information you provided.

Comment: Yep, just figured that out. People drive from their homes to snowmobile desinations. For example 158 people drove from Edmonton AB to Revelstoke BC (700km). these are the trips i want to show on the map. I am not interested where they go on their snowmobiles, rather where they drive from to go snowmobiling.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to automatically depict **from node to node straight line segments (say flows)**; you can check for the **Flow Mapper QGIS plugin**.

Provide input nodes and interaction matrix between nodes as white space deliminated text file, then plugin will automatically generate them in a shapefile.

http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/FlowMapper/